# Venn diagram color options

Tags: r, colors, venn-diagram

Why am I getting an orange color? And where can I get all the color options from?

This is the script I use:

```
> library(VennDiagram)
>draw.pairwise.venn(28, 49, 18, category = c("_d", "_de"), lty = rep("blank", 2), fill = c("blue", "red"), cex=0, alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(25,-25), cat.dist = rep(0.05, 2), scaled = TRUE, inverted = TRUE, rotation.degree = 0)
```

This is the output image:

[image: enter image des an ription here]

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: i am using r...

Comment: Can't you use hex-color notation, ala `#ff0000` for red? See http://www.color-hex.com/

Comment: That's also giving orange color

Answer (score 1):

The color appears as orange because there is an alpha (opacity) setting for the color. You could try setting it to 1, but I don't think that's what you want either.

```
draw.pairwise.venn(28, 49, 18,
                   category = c("_d", "_de"),
                   lty = rep("blank", 2),
                   fill = c("blue", "red"),
                   cex = 0, 
                   alpha = c(0.5, 1),
                   cat.pos = c(25,-25), 
                   cat.dist = rep(0.05, 2), 
                   scaled = TRUE, 
                   inverted = TRUE, 
                   rotation.degree = 0)
```

[image]

I don't know what you mean by "all the color options". Perhaps you should look into the documentation? `?draw.pairwise.venn()`

Comment: blue looks like purple. :-|. may be i need to use photoshop

Comment: it is probably something device-specific and the fact that I didn't change alpha for blue. In any case, you are stuck with colors becoming modified if you set an alpha at anything else than 1. If not, you could try my package eulerr instead, where you do not need to set alpha values for overlaps.

Comment: Thanks for the option. I will look into it.